# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors when adding firebase messaging service to my AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was hoping to add Firebase cloud messaging to my app. I followed [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#8) tutorial for this and it was working correctly for the sample app, but when I try to add `<service>` tags to my application Manifest merger errors occurs.

The strange part is that it is working without adding those services to my Manifest file!

Here it is the error:

> Error:packageName/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-58:19 Error:
>       Element service#packageName.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService at AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-58:19 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:44:9-50:19
>   packageName/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>       Validation failed, exiting
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>     Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

And this is part of my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.violete.selfienight">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="net.violete.selfienight.leafpic.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_camera_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:taskAffinity=".CameraActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
  ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

My question is that whether Firebase library adds these tags to my Manifest during building or something is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the same service (`.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService`) listed twice. This will not work. Either have one `<service>` element containing two `<intent-filter>` elements, or have two separate services with separate classes.

Comment: I think my eyes need a doctor! Thank you so much!

Comment: And why do you think that notifications show even when I don't add services to Manifest? Isn't it strange?

Comment: @NavidEivazzadeh: Sorry, but I do not understand that comment.

Comment: Excuse me for my bad English. Before I add these services to my AndroidManifest file the FCM was working too. I asked why this should happen when my services aren't running?

Comment: @NavidEivazzadeh: I cannot answer that, as I have not used FCM itself, and I have not used GCM (the predecessor to FCM) in a couple of years.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and got fixed by changing the value of minSdkVersion from 15 to 16.