# Manifest and Build Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, kotlin, android-manifest

Got all these errors in a sudden all build errors 
"Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors in Android Studio"

that's when i do the replace suggestion by android studio when i don't i get this one

"Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-43:19 to override."

that's the Manifest

```
 <application

            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/messengered"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/messengered"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
            >

        <activity android:name=".NewMessegesActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                       android:value=".LatestMessagesActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LatestMessagesActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>
```

this is the app gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

after i tried the marked solution i got a compilation error and fixed it with changing the dependencies from 'android.support' to 'androidx.support' like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

then reassigned the layouts to 'AppCompatActivity()' cuz it went in errors that will fix it in the Manifest

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28106780/2607144

Comment: Try this to troubleshoot your problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Adding Firebase Messaging - Menifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783967/android-adding-firebase-messaging-menifest-merger-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your build uses both the old `com.android.support` namespace as well as the new `androidx` namespace.

To solve exactly this problem google created their "jetifier" tool, see [StackOverflow/What is Jetifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier) for more information and how to use it.

Comment: i tried this solution and it got me a compilation error
Note:" i uninstalled Android studio and reinstalled it again"