# Manifest manager failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am an android learner and I am stuck at one of the error and cannot find the solution to this. Actually, I did not understand the meaning of this error. How to fix this error?? If anyone could tell me I will be grateful. Thanks in advance

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-23:19 to override.

Comment: Try this answer to troubleshoot your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Comment: you are using both androidx and support lib in your project, that's why you got this issue please migrate your project in androidx

Comment: check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025

Comment: I am making a clone application in android and for that, I am using some support library  may I know which support library I should discard

Answer (score 0):

There is some attributes duplication with libs you are using. And error already shows the solution.

Just place below line in you manifest file's application tag.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to is migrate to andoridx

Follow these steps:-

1) Click on refractor and choose, migrate to androidx.

2) Then it will automatically ask for backup and then do refractor.

hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you still facing the same problem you can try this code. Add these line in

`<application......`

> tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
>
> android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">

`.....
</application>`