# How to fix 'Manifest merger failed' in react-native android?

Tags: android, react-native

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-60:19 to override.

This is after upgrading react-native version

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rugbyvault"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':tipsi-stripe')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-sound')
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':instabug-reactnative')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: This may help you in troubleshooting your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Adding Firebase Messaging - Menifest merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783967/android-adding-firebase-messaging-menifest-merger-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that latest version of react-native uses AndroidX libraries. So you need to upgrade your dependencies (in your case: *appcompat* and *multidex*) to AndroidX.

FYI: AndroidX (*androidx.**) is new bundle of android support libraries (*com.android.support.**).

You should replace this lines:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

With this ones:

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex::2.0.1'
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
```

---

Putting these flags in your `gradle.properties` can fix some relative issues:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works. But getting other errors related to firebase,
```
/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/notifications/RNFirebaseNotificationManager.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
      LocalBroadcastManager
      ^
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class RNFirebaseNotificationManager
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: delete `node_modules` directory and run a fresh `npm install`