# ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, manifest, androidx

I was importing a project to android studio. While syncing I am getting this error. I tried my level best to solve this but I failed all the time..
I seriously don't get this error.

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be
>   smaller than version 14 declared in library
>   [androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01]
>   C:\Users\abhishekdhyani.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6b4bcb484765b24d3e1d43d0fe4245f4\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 7     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 7,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 14,      or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.recyclerview" to force usage (may lead
>   to runtime failures)

It is showing that my minsdkversion is 7 while it is 18 in my build.gradle. I don't know how to solve it.

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.bingobey"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 66
        versionName "2.26"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
```

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be
>   smaller than version 14 declared in library
>   [androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01]
>   C:\Users\abhishekdhyani.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6b4bcb484765b24d3e1d43d0fe4245f4\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 7     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 7,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 14,      or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.recyclerview" to force usage (may lead
>   to runtime failures)

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 options to solve this problem:
1. You need to increase the SDK-version in `build.gradle(app)` or under Settings -> Gradle
and/or
2. Change the implementation of your `RecyclerView` in `build.gradle(app)` to a lower version. This one you are using here (`androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01`) is the newest version.
You probably need this: `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7`
More of this, I suggest to watch this official Android Developer Migrating site:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually same project is working perfectly on another machine.

Comment: Perfect! If you could tick my answer as the correct one, it would help others, if they have the same problem. They will find the solution faster. Good luck in your further projects!