# Android: Regarding Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

Android: Regarding Manifest merger failed:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Nodir Mach) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-35 is also present at [com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-291:19 to override.

Comment: In future, if you face any manifest merger issue, you can debug this by your own following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(Nodir
>   Mach) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:9-35 is also present at
>   [com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41
>   value=(@string/app_name). Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:label"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-291:19 to override.

You have `android:label` inside your library module `AndroidManifest.xml`, so it clashed with your app module. As the error suggest you, add `tools:replace="android:label"` to your app module AndroidManifest.xml. Something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 package="com.your.package">

    <application
      android:icon="mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="application name"
      tools:replace="android:label"

      ...
    >

     ...

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Where should i put the tools:replace="android:label" line

<application
        android:name="com.online.nodirmach.utils.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Nodir Mach"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

Comment: so, should I use tools:replace="android:name" in MODULE manifest, or MAIN_APP manifest?